# How to prove (2 ^ 2)%R = 4%R

Tags: coq

How to prove the following in Coq?

```
Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.

Definition f (x:R) :R := pow x 2.

Lemma f_2: f 2 = 4%R.
Proof.
Admitted.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach 1: use a powerful tactic.

The `ring` tactic is powerful enough to easily unify `2^2` and `4`. You'll have to unfold `f` since it isn't a ring operation, though.

```
Lemma f_2: f 2 = 4%R.
Proof.
  unfold f.
  ring.
Qed.
```

---

Approach 2: the hard path. To see everything that's implicit in the simple statement `f 2 = 4`, it'll help to turn off notations temporarily. I also opened the scope `R_scope` so that I didn't need the `%R` suffix everywhere.

We get something like `eq (f (IZR (Zpos (xO xH)))) (IZR (Zpos (xO (xO xH))))`

`IZR` is the function that converts integers to real numbers. Let's unfold that, as well as `f`.

Now we can turn notations back on, and we get `IPR 2 ^ 2 = IPR 4` as the goal. So continue by unfolding `IPR`. (`IPR` converts *positive* integers to real numbers).

The goal is then `IPR_2 1 ^ 2 = IPR_2 2`. `IPR_2` also converts positive integers to reals, but introduces a factor of 2. It's basically a convenience function for `IPR`. Unfold it too.

Finally we're down to basic constants. The goal is `(R1 + R1) ^ 2 = (R1 + R1) * (R1 + R1)`. Let's simplify the power. One of the simplification tactics like `cbn` would work. The goal becomes `(R1 + R1) * ((R1 + R1) * 1) = (R1 + R1) * (R1 + R1)`. So finally, we can use that `x * 1 = x`. Searching for `"*"` (better yet, `Search (?x * 1 = ?x).`), I found that `Rmult_1_r` is what we want. Use `rewrite Rmulti_1_r` and then `reflexivity`.

```
Lemma f_2: f 2 = 4.
Proof.
  unfold f, IZR.
  unfold IPR.
  unfold IPR_2.
  cbn.
  (* Search (?x * 1 = ?x). *)
  rewrite Rmult_1_r.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Of course, all those unfold steps are purely computational, so we could skip to the end by saying something like `change 4 with (2 * 2).`, but it's definitely not obvious that `4` is defined to be `2 * 2` unless you're already familiar with how integers get transferred to real numbers.

```
Lemma f_2: f 2 = 4.
Proof.
  unfold f; cbn.
  change 4 with (2 * 2).
  rewrite Rmult_1_r.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to expose the definition of function `f` by "unfolding" it:

```
Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.  (* "Require Import Reals." would be OK as well. *)
Definition f (x : R) : R := pow x 2.

Lemma f_2 : f 2 = 4%R.
Proof.
unfold f.
```

Then you get:

```
1 subgoal

  ============================
  (2 ^ 2)%R = 4%R
```

and one idiomatic way to discharge this goal over the *axiomatized reals* is to rely on the `ring` tactic:

```
ring.
Qed.
```

For more details on this tactic, see the [official Coq doc](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.11/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html?highlight=ring#coq:tacn.ring).